# SQL: Return unique entries of only first table in a multi table join

Tags: sql

I'm relatively new to sql so this may probably come off as a simple questions.

I have 3 tables A,B,C
B has a FK to A, and C has a FK to B
I would like to get all the distinct entries in A that has an entry in B that corresponds to an entry in C.  With JOINs I currently have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Peoples p
INNER JOIN Contracts c 
ON p.pkey=c.person_pkey
JOIN audits a ON c.contract_pkey=a.contract_issued_for;
```

So this returns the list of all people (with duplicates) with an audit.  How do I get it so that instead of return columns of all the tables put together, but rather just all the columns that belong to table peoples and are unique entries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
```

with

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM Peoples p
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The minimal change to your query would be to change `*` to `p.*`. However, I think a better approach is to use `IN` clauses rather than `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Peoples
 WHERE pkey IN
        ( SELECT person_pkey
            FROM Contracts
           WHERE contract_pkey IN
                  ( SELECT contract_issued_for
                      FROM audits
                  )
        )
;
```

This makes clear what the query is really doing: it's finding people who have contracts that audits have been issued for, and is not otherwise interested in those contracts or audits.